# Google Keyboard (gboard) adds word fragments on backspace

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, gboard

I have a strange behavior with my Google Keyboard on a Motorola Moto E (2nd Generation, LTE) with Android 6.0. Occasionally pressing the backspace key will result in adding word fragments. In the following GIF I only press the backspace button from frame to frame. This is really annoying because I try to just delete the last word and then have to cycle through this.

[image]

Is there somewhere I could file this bug? Is there *any* hope that this would be eventually fixed for my phone?

Comment: Try clearing cache of the keyboard app

Comment: I tried that, it happened again after that.

Answer (score -2):

Gboard keyboard settings-> text correction-> disable auto correction.

Comment: This will of course get rid of this problem, but that will disable autocompletion as a while. I am quite happy with autocompletion, just not this particular bug in it.